# Which programming language to pre-populate HTML div, based on date?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Which programming language would a designer/developer use in order to "pre-populate" events on a website based on the date the events would happen?

For example: suppose you have a restaurant, and each day you have a different "lunch special" or something.  And on the homepage of the website, you've got a div that says "today's lunch special," followed by whatever the special that day is.  Suppose you know what the special is going to be for the next 30 days, each day.  January 1 - sandwiches.  January 2nd - soup.  January 3rd - pizza.  and so on.

Would there be a way to put all of this information in ahead of time (presumably some kind of database), so that on January 2nd, the website automatically changes to "soup," on January 3rd, it changes to "pizza," etc etc?  would it be possible to put the info in ahead of time, and have the site populate the info based on the date?  or would you just have to go into the HTML every day, change it, then upload it to the server?

I'm assuming there is a way to do this, but I have no idea what kind of language one would use to do it.  Maybe PHP for the data, then JavaScript to call on the data?  I'm a bit of a newbie so any advice would be welcome.

Comment: best i can say is -php if you want the information to be sucked from the db and shown on the web page. JS for dynamic user interactive content

Comment: use the `moment() js` programming language ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three fundamental ways to do this:

1. **On the server**: In this situation, your server-side code (PHP, Perl, Java, C#, Python, JavaScript running on NodeJS/SilkJS/etc., or almost any other language) responds to the request for the page and builds the HTML on-the-fly; what gets sent to the browser is the complete, pre-filled page. A single HTTP request is made (for the main page; there will presumably be CSS and images and such).
2. **On the client**: In this situation, the page that is returned by the URL is static, but then it contains JavaScript code that makes a second request for the data from the server via another URL. Server-side code on *that* URL runs, returns the data to the client (typically as JSON or XML), and the client-side JavaScript code interprets that data and fills in the page. Note that there's still server-side code involved, but the code actually filling in the page is on the client. Since it's on the client (browser), this'll be JavaScript. At least two HTTP requests are made (one for the main page, one for the data).
3. **On the client, take 2**: The main URL is handled by server-side code, but the server-side code returns static HTML (as in #2) but with the data the client would request in #2 embedded in the page. Client-side code reads the embedded data and fills in the page. Again that code would be JavaScript. A single HTTP request is made (other than CSS and such).

#2 seems a bit silly — why make two HTTP requests? — but isn't uncommon for sites with large, complex HTML pages: They serve those large static pages from a CDN (Content Delivery Network, a high-speed, usually static-pages-only way to get data to end users) and allow them to be cached, and the dynamic data from a server that just responds to data requests and doesn't allow caching those responses.

#3 is for the case where you may request updates to the data while viewing the page. So you want the client-side code to have the logic for populating the page, but you want to minimize HTTP requests when the user arrives to start with. So you pre-bake the first set of data into the page, but then periodically request updates, which is why you use client-side code to populate the page.

---

Above I've said that the client-side code would have to be JavaScript. It has to be JavaScript by the time it reaches the browser, but there are now several languages that "compile" to JavaScript, such as TypeScript, CoffeeScript, and Dart. So if you liked, you could write your code in one of those languages and "compile" it to JavaScript to send to the browser.

Comment: above and beyond for such a vague question on S.O